# Why FileUriExposedException not occur when calling ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE on Android N

Tags: android, android-intent, android-mediascanner

This doesn't throw FileUriExposedException:

```
Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE );
mediaScanIntent.setData( Uri.fromFile( new File( path ) ) );
context.sendBroadcast( mediaScanIntent );
```

This does:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction( Intent.ACTION_VIEW );
intent.setDataAndType( Uri.fromFile( new File( path ) ), "image/*" );
context.startActivity( Intent.createChooser( intent, "View image" ) );
```

I was expecting a FileUriExposedException on the first one, as well?

Comment: You have to use FileProvider If your targetSdkVersion >= 24 just refer this answer  https://stackoverflow.com/a/38858040/5514839

Comment: @RahulGoswami Yes, the second code snippet does throw an exception if I don't use a FileProvider. But the first code snippet doesn't throw an exception if I don't use a FileProvider. That's what I'm trying to figure out: why doesn't the first code snippet throw an exception when targetSdkVersion >= 24?